# Not able to run methods parallel using joblib in my PyQT5 application,

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pyqt, pyqt5, joblib

I m quite new to PyQT5 parallel programming. I have 10 methods that I want to run parallelly in my GUI, I get an abort on the Joblib that I use.

I get `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object`. I try to use enumerator but still I get an abort.

---

**My error message:**

```
joblib.externals.loky.process_executor._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 418, in _process_worker
    r = call_item()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/externals/loky/process_executor.py", line 272, in __call__
    return self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 567, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 225, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "job_parallel.py", line 73, in button_click_parallel
    Parallel(n_jobs=8)(delayed(command_list[i]()) for i in range(10))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 934, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 432, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable function object
Abort trap: 6
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import threading


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    #uart_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.x_size = 800
        self.y_size = 650
        self.setFixedSize(self.x_size, self.y_size)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        buttons = list()

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ONE", self)
        self.button1.move(100,100)
        buttons.append(self.button1)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TWO", self)
        self.button2.move(100,150)
        buttons.append(self.button2)

        for button in buttons:
            button.clicked.connect(self.button_click_parallel)

        self.show()

    def run_iot_uart1(self):
        print("Job 1")

    def run_iot_uart2(self):
        print("Job 2")

    def run_iot_uart3(self):
        print("Job 3")

    def run_iot_uart4(self):
        print("Job 4")

    def run_iot_uart5(self):
        print("Job 5")

    def run_iot_uart6(self):
        print("Job 6")

    def run_iot_uart7(self):
        print("Job 7")

    def run_iot_uart8(self):
        print("Job 8")

    def run_iot_uart9(self):
        print("Job 9")

    def run_iot_uart10(self):
        print("Job 10")


    def button_click_parallel(self): # Click any button, process all UART in parallel
        command_list=[self.run_iot_uart1, self.run_iot_uart2, self.run_iot_uart3,
                      self.run_iot_uart4, self.run_iot_uart5, self.run_iot_uart6,
                      self.run_iot_uart7, self.run_iot_uart8, self.run_iot_uart9,
                      self.run_iot_uart10]
        Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(command_list[i]()) for i in range(10))
       sys.stdout.flush()

def run():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be in your `Parallel` setup. I haven't used this library myself previously, but the documentation gives the following example, where `collect` is a function.

```
Parallel(n_jobs=2)(
    delayed(collect)(i) 
    for i in range(5)
)
```

Here the *function* is passed to delayed, and the parameters for that function are passed as arguments to the result of that call. That is

```
delayed_function = delayed(function)
delayed_function(arg)
```

In your example code you're getting the function via `command_list[i]` and then calling it immediately `command_list[i]()` then passing the *result* of that function (a string) to `delayed`.

```
Parallel(n_jobs=10)(
    delayed(command_list[i]()) 
    for i in range(10)
)
```

I think what you're looking for is

```
Parallel(n_jobs=10)(
    delayed(command_list[i])()
    for i in range(10)
)
```

#### Cannot pickle x

After making that change to your code I still receive the following error —

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/joblib/parallel.py", line 183, in 
delayed
pickle.dumps(function)
TypeError: can't pickle Window objects
```

This occurs because Parallel uses `pickle` (a Python serialization format) to send functions and arguments to the executors. Unfortunately it looks as though `QWindow` (and probably other Qt objects?) are not pickleable. Because your window methods need access to `self` this needs to be pickled.

The solution is to move these methods either a) to a pickleable class, b) to functions. Below I've done the second.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import threading

def run_iot_uart1():
    print("Job 1")

def run_iot_uart2():
    print("Job 2")

def run_iot_uart3():
    print("Job 3")

def run_iot_uart4():
    print("Job 4")

def run_iot_uart5():
    print("Job 5")

def run_iot_uart6():
    print("Job 6")

def run_iot_uart7():
    print("Job 7")

def run_iot_uart8():
    print("Job 8")

def run_iot_uart9():
    print("Job 9")

def run_iot_uart10():
    print("Job 10")


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    #uart_list = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.x_size = 800
        self.y_size = 650
        self.setFixedSize(self.x_size, self.y_size)
        self.setWindowTitle("Test")

        buttons = list()

        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("ONE", self)
        self.button1.move(100,100)
        buttons.append(self.button1)

        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("TWO", self)
        self.button2.move(100,150)
        buttons.append(self.button2)

        for button in buttons:
            button.clicked.connect(self.button_click_parallel)

        self.show()

    def button_click_parallel(self): # Click any button, process all UART in parallel
        command_list=[run_iot_uart1, run_iot_uart2, run_iot_uart3,
                      run_iot_uart4, run_iot_uart5, run_iot_uart6,
                      run_iot_uart7, run_iot_uart8, run_iot_uart9,
                      run_iot_uart10]
        Parallel(n_jobs=10)(delayed(command_list[i])() for i in range(10))
        sys.stdout.flush()

def run():
    QtWidgets.QApplication.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Running this and pressing button "ONE" I get the following output.

```
martin@Martins-MacBook-Pro temp $ python3 parallel.py
Job 1
Job 3
Job 2
Job 4
Job 5
Job 6
Job 7
Job 8
Job 9
Job 10
```

Comment: I changed my Parallel steup as you suggested but I get the  `PicklingError: Could not pickle the task to send it to the workers. `

Comment: @danglingpointer I got a slightly different error when trying to run the example, but I suspect it's related? Have updated the answer.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for your valuable information that gave a direction to the issue I face.